# how to focus on jbutton placed over another jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

i have two jbuttons of different sizes. I have placed smaller jbutton over other jbutton of bigger size. I have also added MouseListener to bigger size jbutton which is performing some action on mouse OnClick.

The problem is that, i want to change the control of mouse from bigger size jbutton to smaller size jbutton when mouse comes over smaller size jbutton, which is currently not happening.

No action is performed when i am clicking on smaller size jbutton.

Can anybody please tell me how i can fix this problem.

Code snippet:

```
CustomButtom button1 = new CustomButton(icon, null, null);
CustomButton button2 = new CustomButton(icon1, iconRollover, iconPressed);

button1.setBounds(new Rectangle(542,14,115,86));
button2.setBounds(new Rectangle(634,79,24,22));

button1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(){
     performing some task
 }

 //rest of the methods are same. 

});
class CustomButton extends JButton()
{
  public CustomButton(Icon icon, Icon rollover, Icon pressed)
  {
    super(icon);
    setRolloverEnabled(false);
    setRolloverIcon(rollover);
    setPressedIcon(pressed);
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
  }
}
```

Thanks
Jyoti

Comment: Hi Jyoti, can you please post a simple self-contained code example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi Steve, I have put the code snippet. Please suggest something.

Comment: a simple, self-contained code example http://sscce.org/ is more likely to get better guidance. It might also help to explain why you want overlapping buttons.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code you never add a listener to Button2, therefore it will never get a mouse event.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have added the listener to button2, but it still not working.

Comment: Please post a complete working example, it is unclear what you are doing (or not doing).